# CDbCommand query

Tags: php, sql, yii

I would like to bring in php to a CDbCommand query where `id=:id`. I would like to do `id=: $model->id`.

```
$user = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
->select('id, username, profile')
->from('tbl_user u')
->join('tbl_profile p', 'u.id=p.user_id')
->where('id=:id')
->queryRow();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `->where('id=:id', array(':id'=> $model->id))`.

Answer (score 0):

In where clause you can match attribute to an parameter value and then specify parameter value using an associative array.

```
Where('id=:id',array(':id'=> $model->id)).
```